# is this syntax correct in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

is the syntax of the jquery correct?

the first two lines in the code of jquery

```
$("input[name='title']").val(json.title);
$("input[name='age']").val(json.age);
```

is two insert data in the forms

the next line is to display all the echoed elements in the server:

```
$('#age').html(json).show();//at age part of the html
```

the first two lines inserting elements in the form works fine,but displaying the echo elements does not work fine..is there anything wrong in the code??

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $.post(
            'script.php',
            { id: $('input[name="id"]', '#myForm').val() },
            function(json) { 
                $("input[name='title']").val(json.title);
                $("input[name='age']").val(json.age);
                $('#age').html(json).show();
            },
            "json"
        );
    });
 });

 <div id="age"></div>
```

Comment: One bit is wrong, but I don't know if it is your problem.  The attribute selectors (`$("input[name='age']")`) always need to use double-quotes around the attribute value: `$('input[name="age"]')`

Comment: @mazzzzz - That is not necessary.

Comment: there is a typo in code here ..in my actual code i made sure all the brackets are closed properly ..

Comment: @mazzzzz, `$('input[name=age]')` works just fine

Comment: I realized my mistake, I had seen that before, and not checked it.  My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$('#age').html(json).show();
```

The `html()` function is expectiong a string. You're passing it the JSON object that you got back.

Comment: title and age are returned as a json using jason_encode ..there are some parts of the code which just echos as a normal php function...am i interpreting anything wrong?? any suggestions in code..

Comment: What do you mean by that? When you inspect the return value from that AJAX request, what exactly do you see?

Comment: well the user enters the id in the first form all the other forms will be filled using json...sometimes when there is no id the php echo's something like no id which is not json encoded..

Comment: Now I get it: You're first doing `echo json_encode($something);`, then later in the code you do `echo 'something else';`. In that case, your request does not return valid JSON. You'll have to either include that 3rd value in your array/object that you pass to `json_encode()`, or you'll have to do 2 separate AJAX requests.

Comment: hey thankss a lot for your time..i am kind of nobb in jquery can give me a small code snippet for the above you said..thanks in advance

Comment: Just posted my PHP code..plzz ignore if there are some errors in closing or opening brackets

Comment: @John let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2596/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-john)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){` is missing its closing brackets. Add `});` at the end of your javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  


});
```

Comment: its a typo.in the actual code actually it is present..thank u anyway